# IBM Worklight 5.0.6 - iOS 7 app crashes due to "'[WLPhoneGapDelegate initialize] Can't read checksum.js'"

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, ios7, worklight-studio

Just wanted to raise a small question about iOS7 support for Worklight 5.0.6. We will be using this Worklight version for our first launch and testers started testing with iOS7 beta4. Of course, we know it is still a beta iOS and not a really reliable assessment of the final iOS7, but some people are getting worried.

Is that known? Is there/Will there be a fix to support iOS7 with Worklight 5.0.6.

This is what the console of the phone is giving us:

```
Jul 31 17:46:48 iPhone kernel[0] <Debug>: launchd[294] Container: /private/var/mobile/Applications/8AAE4BC2-E2DF-40D2-81EB-F7AF0ECB5650 (sandbox)
Jul 31 17:46:48 iPhone networkd[82] <Warning>: Analytics Engine: double ON for app: com.app.mobileapp
Jul 31 17:46:48 iPhone UserEventAgent[14] <Warning>: watchdog: lossy conversion tmp=cda92cf1
Jul 31 17:46:48 iPhone APP[294] <Warning>: Need to switch from cache dir to app support dir
Jul 31 17:46:48 iPhone APP[294] <Warning>: CoreAnimation: warning, deleted thread with uncommitted CATransaction; set CA_DEBUG_TRANSACTIONS=1 in environment to log backtraces.
Jul 31 17:46:48 iPhone APP[294] <Error>: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception '[WLPhoneGapDelegate initialize] Can't read checksum.js', reason: 'The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 258.)'
        *** First throw call stack:
        (0x3098210b 0x3aae06c7 0x3098204d 0x1b89a7 0x1bbbe1 0x1b96fb 0x3138c23f 0x3b111175 0x3b111043 0x3b114b34)
Jul 31 17:46:48 iPhone ReportCrash[295] <Notice>: ReportCrash acting against PID 294
Jul 31 17:46:48 iPhone ReportCrash[295] <Notice>: Formulating crash report for process APP[294]
Jul 31 17:46:48 iPhone com.apple.launchd[1] (UIKitApplication:com.app.mobileapp[0x4f4b][294]) <Warning>: (UIKitApplication:com.app.mobileapp[0x4f4b]) Job appears to have crashed: Abort trap: 6
Jul 31 17:46:48 iPhone backboardd[28] <Warning>: Application 'UIKitApplication:com.app.mobileapp[0x4f4b]' exited abnormally with signal 6: Abort trap: 6
Jul 31 17:46:48 iPhone ReportCrash[295] <Notice>: Saved crashreport to /var/mobile/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/APP_2013-07-31-174648_iPhone.plist using uid: 0 gid: 0, synthetic_euid: 501 egid: 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Known and fixed.
The fix was released yesterday.

- For 5.0.6.x: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27039253
- For 6.0, simply check for updates in Eclipse.

(And before you mention it - yes, there is a visual bug you'll probably notice; yes, we know about it as well... :)

Comment: A follow up consideration that is important for our client:Does IBM Worklight commit to fully support iOS7 with 5.0.6 and is there a timeframe available for the fix of the "visual bug" and the full support of iOS7 (right when available; or with some delay?) Thank you.