# IBM Worklight 6.0 - Is iOS7 deployment unsupported with v6.0.0.20130614-0631?

Tags: ios, ios7, ibm-mobilefirst

I have a machine with Eclipse Juno and the Worklight Developer edition 6.0.0.20130614-0631 plugin.

I have developed two different applications using it and I have moved them to an Apple environment for testing on iOS 7 devices (specifically an iPhone 4) using XCode 4.6.

The first application run without problems, for the second one i get, when i run it from the device, this error:

> [WLPhoneGapDelegate initialize] Can't read checksum.js reason:'The completation can't be completed'

i saw there is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17983018/ibm-worklight-5-0-6-ios-7-app-crashes-due-to-wlphonegapdelegate-initialize) but using Eclipse i can't find any available update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the question in the title - Yes.

You must upgrade to a version of Worklight containing (many) fixes for iOS7 - Worklight 6.0.0.1 
fix pack 1 (**6.0.0.20130926**).
See this IBM technote: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27039574

Also, I believe the version available via the Eclipse Marketplace has by now updated to 6.0.0.20130926 as well.

Note that you should also use Xcode 5.

Comment: Hi Idan, i check for updates using Eclipse but it can't find any. How can i update it?

Comment: Read the technote? Also in a fresh download from the Marketplace I do get this version, so you need to clarify how you've installed Worklight, and from where.

Comment: upgraded to v6.0.0.20130926-1933, nothing changed, still getting the same error on deploying the application on iOS7.

Comment: for what concerns Xcode's version i've red that Worklight v6.0 is fully compatible with Xcode v4.5. maybe this is not true?

Comment: If you haven't done this, also delete the native folder and re-build the worklight project before opening the generated Xcode project in Xcode.

Comment: The IBM technote specifically states that if you'd like to develop for iOS 7, you need to use Xcode 5. It also mentions to delete the native folder, as I've mentioned above. Please follow the instructions provided in the technote.

Comment: Hi Idan, i installed v6.0.0.20130926, got the iPhone package and build the xcode project using XCode v5. i'm still getting the same error.

Comment: if it can be useful after that i installed the Worklight v6.1 from the Eclipse's marketplace. This works with the development server but fails on production for incompatibility with the installed version of Worklight server(v6.0). Unfortunately i can't upgrade worklight server's version right now.